# Is INET socket family supported in JAVA?

Tags: java, sockets, inet

I want to build a user application which will interact with a kernel part over INET socket family. Is INET socket family supported in JAVA?

Answer (score 2):

yes INET is supported in java

I hope following programm will be helpful to you

```
import java.net.*; 
class InetAddressTest 
{ 
public static void main(String args[]) throws 
UnknownHostException { 
InetAddress Address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();  
System.out.println(Address); 
Address = InetAddress.getByName("starwave.com"); 
System.out.println(Address); 
InetAddress SW[] = InetAddress.getAllByName("www.nba.com"); 
for (int i=0; i<SW.length; i++) 
System.out.println(SW[i]); 
}  
}
```

Comment: INET refers to the internet address. I am asking about AF_INET family of sockets which is an enhanced form of IOCTL. Please clarify.